# Replace string from even lines and column two of file using shell

Tags: linux

I have a manually created gff file. Every line is duplicated, I need to replace the string "gene" from column two of every even line to the string "cds".

My file looks like this:

```
NC_002929.2 Seq gene    3653563 3653611 .   +   .   Pred285
NC_002929.2 Seq gene    3653563 3653611 .   +   .   Pred285
NC_002929.2 Seq gene    2902987 2903162 .   -   .   rgtA
NC_002929.2 Seq gene    2902987 2903162 .   -   .   rgtA
```

I want it to look like this :

```
NC_002929.2 Seq gene    3653563 3653611 .   +   .   Pred285
NC_002929.2 Seq cds     3653563 3653611 .   +   .   Pred285
NC_002929.2 Seq gene    2902987 2903162 .   -   .   rgtA
NC_002929.2 Seq cds     2902987 2903162 .   -   .   rgtA
```

The actual file is a lot bigger than this, this is just a small example. Can anybody help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try also this `awk` approach:

```
awk  -F"[ ]" '!(NR%2) {sub (/gene/, "cdc ", $3); $NF = "ID=" $NF}  1' file
NC_002929.2 Seq gene    3653563 3653611 .   +   .   Pred285
NC_002929.2 Seq cdc     3653563 3653611 .   +   .   ID=Pred285
NC_002929.2 Seq gene    2902987 2903162 .   -   .   rgtA
NC_002929.2 Seq cdc     2902987 2903162 .   -   .   ID=rgtA
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you have GNU sed with the *n skip m* address operator, and that the string `gene` cannot occur anywhere before the second column:

```
sed '2~2s/gene/cds/' file.gff
```

Note that sed has no intrinsic concept of "columns" - the `2~2` here refers to every 2nd *line* starting at the 2nd *line*, and the replacement matches the first occurrence of `gene` in the line.

---

To apply a replacement to the last "column" you would need to do something like matching non-blank characters anchored to the end of the line, ex.

```
sed -r '2~2{s/gene/cds/; s/[^[:blank:]]+$/ID=&/;}' file.gff
```

If you want something truly column-oriented, then try awk, perl, or miller.

Comment: Thank you Steeldriver, it worked perfect :)

Comment: Could you please help me with another problem, I need the prefix "ID=" infront of the last column of every even line. I tried this code but it gives the prefix infron tof the first column instead .   sed -e '9~2s/^/ID=/' file.gff > file.new

Comment: @saamarrajput please see edit